# Write raw bytes to SD card on Windows

Tags: windows, sd-card

I am working on an embedded systems project in which we need to store some data on an SD card and read it with an FPGA. It would be simplest not to deal with a file system in this case, so I would like to find a way to write raw bytes to an SD card on my Windows machine. That is, I have a raw binary file, or maybe a .mif file or something of that nature, and I write the contents of the file starting at address 0 right on to the SD card, no FAT32 file system or anything like that.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite raw disk editor is HxD Hex Editor. Just select the Physical Disk of your SD card, not Logical Disk.